# Whats is the diference between next lint and eslint

Tags: next.js, eslint

I just created a new project using NextJS and I noticed that comes with lint, specifically the eslint.

In the *package.json* I noticed that the invocation of eslint seems to be different

Whats is the diference between `next lint` and `eslint .`?